# Render JSON for a DataTable inside a Bootstrap modal opened via an ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables, bootstrap-4

Using DataTables 1.10.18, Bootstrap 4 and jQuery 3.2.1

My application consists of a page containing anchors such as:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/foo.json" data-target="#affectedSubstances">Modal 1</a>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="/bar.json" data-target="#affectedSubstances">Modal 2</a>
```

When the user clicks on one of these anchors I want to do the following:

1. Open a Bootstrap 4 modal
2. Make an ajax request to the `href` of the anchor they clicked. The response from this is JSON, from which I want to build my DataTable.
3. Using the response data from (2) initialize a DataTable inside the modal.

The DataTables may contain >100 rows so I want to paginate them and use `serverSide` mode of DataTables, i.e. each paginated page makes a new ajax request and then writes the data back to the table *inside the modal*.

I'm struggling to piece all of this together. This is what I've got so far:

1. Opening the modal is trivial. I wait for a click on `[data-toggle="modal"]` and then write the response to `.modal-body` inside `#affectedSubstances`:

   ```
   $('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(){
       $($(this).data("target")+' .modal-body').load($(this).attr("href"));
   });
   ```

   The markup which I have for `#affectedSubstances` is simply an empty modal, i.e. `.modal-body` has no content and I'm writing the loaded JSON data into it.

   The above simply writes the raw JSON string inside `.modal-body`.
2. The code for (1) does the ajax request from `.load()`. At this point I'm unsure whether I'd be better writing it with `$.get()` and then I can use a `.done(response)` callback. The reason I'm thinking this is because I need to wait until I know the ajax response has completed, before I can initialize the table. This seems critical to the problem. So I could easily get rid of my code from (1) and make a normal ajax request like this:

   ```
   $.get($(this).attr("href")).done(function(response) {
       console.log(response);
   });
   ```

   Instead of a modal opening, I'm now just getting the JSON in the console. This is expected.
3. Based on (1) and (2) I know it's possible to request the JSON for the table. But I don't know how/where to initialize the DataTable and pass in this JSON? In other parts of my application I've done things equivalent to:

   ```
   $('#affectedSubstances .modal-body').DataTable({
         processing: true,
         serverSide: true,
         searching: false,
         ajax: {
             url: '/foo.json'
         }
   });
   ```

This won't work because there's no `<table>` element inside `.modal-body`.  Furthermore this relies on passing the `url:` property which in this case needs to be dynamic, because it's the `href` of the link the user has clicked.

I'm unsure where to go with this, but feel I've got together various parts of what's needed.

The last issue is that because I'm using `serverSide: true` - and know the number of rows that might be returned can be larger than I'd want to display inside a modal - I need to make sure that the calls for pagination, for example:

```
 /foo.json?page=2
 /foo.json?page=3
 /foo.json?page=4
```

... still write to the DataTable I have initialized in my modal. I don't know whether DataTables handles this automatically because it's aware of what element it was initialized on. That's how it seems to work in the rest of the application (although none of the other tables are inside a modal, so realise it's different here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load Database only in a `<table>`

1. So we need to add `<table>` inside modal on click (assuming you want a table to be created dynamically), things will be simpler if you add static table inside each modal.
2. Get data from ajax call
3. Load Datatable

Here is working fiddle for some idea

http://jsfiddle.net/7g6ehpo9/

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(){

    var url = $(this).attr("url");
        var tableid = $(this).attr("data-target").replace("#", "");
    var tableBody = '<table class="'+tableid+'_table"  class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <thead> <tr>  <th>First Name</th>  <th>Last Name</th>          <th>Occupation</th>          <th>Email Address</th>        </tr>      </thead>    </table>';

    $("#"+tableid).find(".modal-body").empty();
        $("#"+tableid).find(".modal-body").append(tableBody);

        populateDataTable(data, tableid+"_table");

}); 


 function populateDataTable(data, tableId) {
    $('.'+tableId).DataTable().clear();
    var length = Object.keys(data.customers).length;
    for(var i = 1; i < length+1; i++) {
      var customer = data.customers['customer'+i];
       $('.'+tableId).dataTable().fnAddData( [
        customer.first_name,
        customer.last_name,
        customer.occupation,
        customer.email_address
      ]);
    }
  }

});
```

**With Pagination involve**

Datatable will add some parameters to your ajax call so that you can handle server-side pagination accordingly from the backend.

In the pagination case, the last 2 steps will become one.

[This post](https://ashishontech.xyz/server-side-pagination-jquery-datatable/) might help for more detail with sample code and live demo